# Unlike several Facebook fan pages at once

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to trigger an "Unlike" event of some specified Facebook fan pages via Javascript (or another language) after a button click, so the users can remove their "Like" from the Facebook fan pages that they want to unlike directly in my web page through a simple "Unlike Button" click ?

Comment: Just use the standard like button – if the user already liked the page, it will indicate that, and they can un-like it again right there.

Comment: @CBroe I actually need to implement a functionality to unlike "many" specified Facebook fan pages at once with a simple button click. The standard like button isn't relevant for my case I guess!

Comment: Facebook pages can only be liked/unliked using the official like button. Besides, I can’t really see what _legitimate_ use case this could have.

Comment: @CBroe It's for a noble reason, people in the country I live are protesting against dictatorship and scam of the 3 Internet Service Providers by unliking their Facebook fan pages. I already established a web page that measure the loss of their fans and I'm trying now to simplify the process of unliking the 3 ISPs fan pages by 1 simple button click if they choose to participate to the protestation. Why it wouldn't be legitimate if the user choose and want to easily unlike many pages at once with a simple button click?

Comment: Well, that is simply not possible. Again, the FB Like button is the only way to like/unlike a Facebook page.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi +1 for the Noble reason

Answer (score 0):

This would be the only option, but it does not seem to work for Pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes#update

In other words, it´s not possible to remove Page likes with the API. You have to present Like Buttons for that.